# Generate and Store SecretKey

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I'm implementing [AWS S3 SSE-C](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html) (Server Side Encryption with Client's key), I have all the necessary code to store files and as well as retrieve it. Now the last step is to figure out the best way/practice to generate Key and store it properly in the application.

Here is the code that is taken from [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sse-c-using-java-sdk.html) that generates key.

```
private static SecretKey generateSecretKey() {
    KeyGenerator generator;
    try {
        generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        generator.init(256, new SecureRandom());
        return generator.generateKey();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I understood this is a randomly generate key that will only be valid once the `SecretKey` is retrieved. How about distributing a key in an app that might have multiple instances (micro services), maybe store as an environment variable.

Comment: Given these questions, why are you using SSE-C at all?  Why not let S3 take care of the keys?

Comment: There is a requirement from the client to maintain keys on our side.